# Optimization method for coefficient matrix in $Ax = b$ with known $x$ and $b$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming, matrix-equations

I have two data vectors $x$ and $b$ which are related to each other by the linear system of equations $Ax = b$, where $A$ represents a transfer matrix, $x$ represents the Stokes vector and $b$ represents the intensity vector of a polarimetric measurement. The ideal transfer matrix $A$ which relates $x$ to $b$ is given as:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}0.5&0.5&0&0\\0.5&0&0.5&0\\0.5&-0.5&0&0\\0.5&0&-0.5& 0\end{bmatrix} \text{(For ideal case)}$$

Now, for each $x$ and $b$, I need to calculate an optimized transfer matrix using the relation $Ax = b$ where $A$ is the above ideal matrix.

What Optimization method is most suitable for this problem and what error metric I should use to optimize elements of $A$ after each iteration?

Comment: You will have to improve the notation in the question, as it currently is confusing as you use the name $A$ for both some given ideal matrix, and a matrix you want to find.

Comment: In order to optimise $A$, you first need to nominate a sense of distance, presumably some [matrix norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm). We need some way to measure if one possible $A$ is better than another. Knowing the ideal matrix $A$ is only sufficient if the ideal matrix maps $x$ to $b$ already! Otherwise, the distance function will radically change the entries in the optimal matrix.